# What exactly happens in telnet/SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, telnet

How does the host machine responds to it?

I tried to find by searching in google. But, I couldn't find any article which explains me better. (May be I am lacking in the googling skills). Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH is a protocol, to understand how the communication between the host and the server happens you will need to read (a lot) about it. Here is a start:

http://www.snailbook.com/protocols.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to read this [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html). Not an easy read, it's for protocol lawyers. But there it is.